# Bootstrap, Popper is missing even after importing bootstrap bundle

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

I'm struggling with bootstrap4. I've imported the `bootstrap.bundle.js` which already contain `popper.js`.

But anyway I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Popper is not defined
```

Including structure

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=".../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".../js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: where you include that show some code   either  you call a function which library is missing or below that function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*bootstrap.bundle.js* or *bootstrap.bundle.min.js* contains Bootstrap + Popper.js so you just have to include jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle and everything is done

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>   
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-3ziFidFTgxJXHMDttyPJKDuTlmxJlwbSkojudK/CkRqKDOmeSbN6KLrGdrBQnT2n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `popper.min.js` to your file

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I don't consider that a solution. Obviously that works, but it's just importing twice a resource. As you can see in from Bootstrap official blog, the bundle already contains popper.js - http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2017/10/19/bootstrap-4-beta-2/